# Python: Ignoring parent __setattr__

Tags: python

Having the following code:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise RuntimeError()


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.y = 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Child().y)
```

And the following conditions/assumptions:

- Class `Parent` does something in its `__setattr__` implementation that makes `Child` raise an exception when setting new class attributes.
- Class `Parent` source code cannot be modified (could be monkey-patched, but it is an external dependency).

Is there a way to fix that? Could I "trash" the `Parent`'s `__setattr__` implementation before setting `y`? Can I re-implement this method in `Child` to make it work as expected?

Comment: you can overload `__setattr__` in the `Child` class.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: Yeah, I tried with `object.__setattr__`, which didn't work, and that's when I asked the question. Now I know the difference between that and `super(Parent, self).__setattr__`. :-)

Comment: i actually meant what i posted as answer below; not call `__setattr__` on `object` but just on `self`. this bypasses all the `__setattrs__`  that might have been definded in the MRO chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bypass the method by looking up the *next* `__setattr__` method in the MRO. Tell `super()` to look *past* `Parent`:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.y = 2

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        # skip Parent.__setattr__
        super(Parent, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```

Note that you should normally *not* use a different class from the current in `super()`; this is an appropriate exception, but do include a comment in your production code to explain why you are doing this.

You *could* use `object.__setattr__(self, name, value)` too, but only if `Parent` inherits directly from `object` and not from some other class that also implements `__setattr__`. Using `super()` will find the *next* `__setattr__` implementation in your inheritance tree.

Demo:

```
>>> class Parent():
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         raise RuntimeError()
...
>>> class Child(Parent):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super().__init__()
...         self.y = 2
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         # skip Parent.__setattr__
...         super(Parent, self).__setattr__(name, value)
...
>>> Child().y
2
```

Comment: you always manage to come up with a more complete answer. thanks! alsways learning a new 'trick'.

Comment: I tried with `object.__setattr__` but somehow that was failing (although my, now I know, bad reduced code sample works with that). Somehow you came with an actual solution and good answer to my bad question (lol).

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer and your advice. Maybe you'd like to add a comment like @Bakuriu's explaining that there is an actual difference between `object.__setattr__` and your approach (and that must be why the former didn't work for me when I tried). Just to make it more complete, and if you have the time/will. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the base `__setattr__`:

```
object.__setattr__(self, 'y', 2)
```

Note that this is completely bypassing `Parent`'s `__setattr__`, so doing this might be breaking various invariants in `Parent`.

Comment: Or better: use `super(Parent, self).__setattr__` in this way if there are multiple classes between `object` and `Parent` and you *do* want to preserve, potentially, what they are doing with it you can, while `object` skips *all* implementations.

Comment: I tried with `object.__setattr__` before asking but somehow that was failing (although my, now I know, bad reduced code sample works with that). Sorry for a bad question and thanks for a correct answer. :-)

Comment: @Bakuriu Good point, but note that `super(Parent, self)...` will also skip the `__setattr__` implementations in mixins located between `Child` and `Parent`, if any. One cannot skip `Parent.__setattr__` anyway without a careful understanding of what it does. Part of that understanding is finding out which `__setattr__` you want called, and calling it. When doing this kind of magic, I find it best to be as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 0):

adding a `__setattr__` method in `Child` you can ignore the one in `Parent`:

```
class Child(Parent):
    ...
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        # do whatever you want;
```